# How to scale a JPanel inside a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

I would like to display a JPanel inside a JPanel where the inner panel has some margin over the outter panel as seen in the following [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MT8d.png):

I tried adding a border into the inner panel with this line:

```
panel2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without seeing the relevant rest of your code. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The outer JPanel is the JPanel that needs an empty border to produce your image.  Although an empty border on all JPanels provides a visual separation of Swing components.